# In sugar.js, how do you find an Array's "last index of" by filtering (not exact match)?

Tags: javascript, sugar.js

It looks like the original functionality of Array.lastIndexOf was what I'm looking for, but it was changed.  Any idea how to replicate the old functionality?

http://blog.sugarjs.com/post/8452749291/v0-9-2-indexof-lastindexof-fixed

Comment: It says "would show some odd behavior when passed either an object or a function" and "Sugar would attempt to run that actual function against elements in the array as an equality check (a la filter), when it should have been doing a strict equals directly on the function itself."  I'm interested in passing an object "(a la filter)".

Comment: Well, since you can't rely on Sugar's implementation to do what you want, why not implement your own `Array.prototype.lastIndexOfFn`? From the blog post it is not apparent what the problem with passing an object is, as it cannot be invoked as a filter on each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the sugar.js docs, it appears that `Array#findIndex` does the reverse of what I'm trying to do, so here's my solution which uses that:

```
Array.prototype.findLastIndex = function(f, startIndex, loop) {
    var reverseIndex = this.clone().reverse().findIndex(f, startIndex, loop);
    if (reverseIndex < 0) {
        return reverseIndex;
    }
    return this.length - reverseIndex - 1;
};
```